# In ECS (Entity Component System) what is the difference between Component-Manager and a System?

Tags: game-engine, entity-component-system

I'm trying to understand ECS. So a component is just plain data, and some manager holds these components in a container and loops through all of them to act on this data, to "update" them.

Is this manager what people call "component-manager" or is it a "system"? Or do they mean the same thing? If not, what does a component-manager and a system do?

Answer (score 2):

ECS means different things to different people. There are a large number of approaches when it comes to implementation but I personally go by the following rules:

- A **Component** is just plain data, typically a structure or some object with no logic associated with it what so ever.
- An **Entity** is a collection of components. It is defined by an identifier, typically an integer, that can be used to look up components like an index.
- A **System** is where all the game logic lives. Each System has an archetype, that is a specific set of components that it operates on. Systems have an update function, which when invoked accesses the specific set of components its interested in (its archetype), for all entities that have that specific collection of components. This update function is triggered externally (by what? see the next paragraph).

Now, here's the bit that addresses your question directly (or at least attempts to). Video games are simulations and they are typically driven by whats called an update loop (typically sync-ed to a monitor's refresh rate). In ECS architecture, there is typically dedicated code that strings your systems together in a queue and on each time-step of the update loop executes those systems in sequence (ie. calls their update functions). That bit of dedicated code not only manages the system update loop but is also responsible for managing components (stored as lists/arrays that can be indexed by an entity id) and a myriad of other tasks. In many implementations its referred to as the "**Engine**". This is what I take to be a "component-manager". But that could mean something else in another ECS approach. Just my two-cents. Hope it helped.